# Get rid of squirrels without poison or bb gun?

Tags: pest-control

The squirrels around my house keep getting in stuff, chewing stuff up, and in general are just causing a mess.

What's the best way to get rid of them? Looking for solutions online it seems I can get either poison or some automated sprinklers.  There has to be more options out there. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are the squirrels doing that is causing a problem?

Comment: They eat everything in our garden and also chew up a considerable amount of stuff. The chewing up of stuff usually occurs closer to winder, so I assume they're getting nesting material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More options:

- dog
- multiple dogs
- traps (live or otherwise)
- cayenne pepper
- squirrel repellant (usually a mix of blood and garlic...your yard will stink)
- squirrel killing robots with laser eyes (not sure those exist, but wish they did)

The only thing that's worked well for me from the above list is the dog, but even that isn't fail-proof. The Cayenne and Repellant seem to work OK, but a) it stinks up the place and b) is only temporary as the squirrels get used to it sooner or later.

Live traps might require some research on local regulations. Many places won't allow you to release the squirrels elsewhere. If they do, then be sure to go FAR away, and, ideally, not in someone else's back yard.

If the issue is them digging up new grass, one thing that can work is chicken wire. Cover the new grass with the chicken wire (stake it down). The squirrels can't dig with the wire there. Granted, this is only a temporary solution for a very specific issue, but might be of some use.

Comment: We did have an old dog about a year ago... I guess she did fairly well keeping the place guarded. I didn't really think about that until you mentioned it. I guess cats don't really do anything? most of my neighbors have outdoor cats.

Comment: Needs pictures (especially the squirrel killing robot).

Comment: @Tester101 - http://xkcd.com/382/

Answer (score 2):

Just read this and my first thought was the trap I bought at Lowes a year or so ago. But, since I've never used it to trap a squirrel, that's just my opinion. So, I did a quick search on "squirrel traps" and found this: http://www.wikihow.com/Trap-a-Squirrel-With-Everyday-Materials. Sounds like fun to me. I'd give it a try.